# How to monkey patch request obj with data in express/connect

Tags: node.js, connect, express

Helllo
Im programming a middleware library to abstract the process of oauth authorize/authenticate and supply own authentication strategies.

I'm stuck because when I monkey patch the request with data it won't be available on any routed request but the other middlewares (connect/express documentation is very poor on this subject).

How can I make the data stick so it would be available to every request (except for static files)?

Thanks.

P.s I don't use other available modules because it was just frustrating to make them work...

Comment: Can you post your app.use(...) and the relevant part(s) of your middleware? This is line is very unclear: `"when I monkey patch the request with data it won't on any routed request"`, can you please go in to more detail. I have worked with connect's middleware quite a bit and this is something I can help you with once we establish what your problem is.

Comment: @Ryan Olds I know,fixed it. Code available here https://github.com/Cu7l4ss/express-oauth-logic-middleware/ in lib.js

Comment: @Ryan Olds in StrategyMaster auth method is the middleware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function authOrDie() {
  return function(req,res,next) {
    console.log(req.isAuthenticated());
    next(); // Have to call next to continue to the next middleware
  };
}
```

I assume `console.log(req.isAuthenticated());` is being run and it's working, I also assume it's printing `false`.

Also, if requests to your static files doesn't need to be authenticated you should move it much higher in the stack.

Comment: This works but since it's a middleware too. But if I try to access attached user data from a regular route (e.g. /posts) It would return undefined. I guess I could reattach the data in the app middleware authentication logic  itself. I just thought that middlewares in the app runs through all the routes and requests..

Comment: Middleware should be able to add to `req` and as long as something doesn't blow it out it should be available in the route's req because it's the same object. `req` is passed by reference down the middleware until one of them handles it or it reaches the end. express.routes is a middleware and whichever route handles the request will get that same `req` object. If it's not set then something is unsetting it.

Comment: Ahh I thought so too. There is a subtle difference between Route middlware and plain app.configure middleware. The difference is that since the route is accessed, it is the first in the app.configure middleware chain so (from what I understood) there is no other way to do this but making sure there is a route middleware too (can be the same method as authOrDie f.e.)

Comment: The express.route middleware should be run in the order that it was added using app.use(). Middleware that you add to a route are pretty much the same was regular middleware and as far as I'm aware they are pretty much interchangeable.

Comment: Apparently I've done something wrong and somehow the middleware execution sequence gone wrong (don't know what happened, probably has to do with the fact that I haven't packaged the module correctly). Thanks!